# Install Mac OS X 10.9 as a virtual machine

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, vmware, disk, macosx

I want to install Mac OS X 10.9 as a virtual machine on my Ubuntu partition (running a dual boot machine Win8/Ubuntu) I have 2 questions:

- Can I install the virtual machine using the empty disk space on another volume than the Ubuntu file system?
- What do you recommend to use to install it?

  - VMWare
  - Virtual Box
  - Something else?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share a video, but it wouldn't be good to put the link here, so the link could be censored.

No, you need to unify the empty disk to the Ubuntu's HHD. VMWare to Virtualbox can't detect the HHDs or the volumes. But if you have enough Ubuntu's HDD, don't unify, firstly install the virtual machine on Ubuntu's HDD, then, move it to the empty disk.

But search "OS X Snow Leopard" at Web UPD8 and you'll find that article. Google at Youtube "How to install Mac OS X Snow Leopard on Ubuntu".

I recommend Virtualbox as that article and the video suggested, so it's very easy to be installed. But VMWare is another good idea.

If you want to use OS X 10.9... firstly you need to install OS X Snow Leopard on a virtual machine and update to 10.6.8, and at 10.6.8, download OS X 10.10 (it's free) (unfortunately OS X 10.9 isn't available).

I recommend you to visit and ask for help at the InsanelyMac (they're good people and help a lot the people to make Hackintosh), but before, I'll give you a tip: please, don't cite iAthos and TonyMacOSX86, so that forum doesn't support them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I saw a post in Lifehacker that shows how to do it with OS X Snow Leopard. I tested in my Ubuntu 14.04 and it worked pretty well. You have to use an OSX86 ISO and your CPU needs to support hardware virtualization, or else this will not work. Lifehacker article mentions that you'll be needing around 1 GB of RAM and that the virtual hard disk size should be around 20GB, you can use less if you don't have enough RAM / HDD space to spare. I've used ~500MB of RAM and a HDD of 11.11 GB to install the latest OSX Snow Leopard in Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx.